# Azure Notification Hub Sending To Subset Of Users Based On Tags

Tags: azure, push-notification, azureservicebus

We have started using the Azure Service Bus NotificationHubClient and we are trying to work out a way to send notifications using tags to a subset of users, for example let's say we have two users:

```
User1 - Tags ('Tag1', 'Tag2')
User2 - Tags ('Tag1', 'Tag3')
```

Is there a way that we could run the following code:

```
NotificationHubClient hub = GetHubclient();
var toast = GetToastNotification();
await hub.SendMpnsNativeNotificationAsync(toast, new List<string>() { "Tag1", "Tag3" });
```

In this situation we would only want User2 to get the notification as they have both 'Tag1' and 'Tag3'.  I guess what we want is for tags to be AND instead of OR.

I can't see a way to do this but any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible.  You can of course create aggregated tags, but I assume you want them to be more flexible.  Would be a nice feature request, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Tag Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx) feature.